# Python Pandas Dataframes : use rows values to create columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to replicate [this article](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) in python, as a general way to improve my pandas skills.

Right now, I am facing the following issue. Page 11 of that document you'll see table12(a) and table2(b). I found the way to get from table11 to table 12(a), but now I am stuck.

I have the following dataframe:

```
    id  date    element value
12  MX17004 2010-02-02  tmax    27.3
13  MX17004 2010-02-02  tmin    14.4
22  MX17004 2010-02-03  tmax    24.1
23  MX17004 2010-02-03  tmin    14.4
44  MX17004 2010-03-05  tmax    32.1
45  MX17004 2010-03-05  tmin    14.2
```

How could I use it to get a "tmax" and a "tmin" columns ?

Of course I could use a for loop, but I read somewhere that every time you find yourself doing complex code when manipulating dataframes, a function already exists that does what you want to do.

My best attempt so far :

```
weather_molten.pivot(index='date', columns='element', values='value')
```

result :

[image]

As you can see, I now have a multiindex DF (quite far from the result in the article), I don't have the 'id' column anymore...

Any idea ?

Thank you for your time !

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? I would like to see your data as text as I can copy paste it into an interpreter quickly.

Comment: hi @coldspeed, thank you for your time. I just edited the post, but I'm afraid I couldn't make the data look really great using text. At least I think it can be copy/pasted. Is it now ok for you ?

Comment: Next time try using [`.to_clipboard()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_clipboard.html) on your dataframe and paste it here in a code block. Other people can then use that raw text again to build a df themselves.

Comment: Awesome @jorijnsmit ! I didn't know that command and it will detinitely make my life easier ! thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were almost there!

[`pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) is a bit different from [`pandas.DataFrame.pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) in that it can handle both (1) multiple columns as an index and also (2) duplicate entries in these indexes.

`weather_molten.pivot_table(index=['id', 'date'], columns='element', values='value')` will do the trick then.

If you are really keen on **not** using multi indexing you could `.reset_index()` to flatten the indexes and fall back onto regular row numbers.

A lot of the mutations described in the article you are referring to are also described on this page in the pandas documentation: [Reshaping and Pivot Tables](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I had pivot_table, but was indeed unkeen on not getting the exact same result as the paper. I came with another circumvoluted way of getting that result, but in the end, you are probably right : pivot_table is the way to go, who cares about the multi-index, as long as we can afterwards easily perform operations on the resulting dataframe ;)